# Getting attributes from Decode Json file and add them as string to a variable on terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider-openstack

I have this Terraform code that decodes a JSON and CSV file

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}

locals {
      resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./ResourceTypes.csv"))
      json_data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/Monitor.json"))
    }

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main" {
      count    =  length(local.resource_groupname)
      name     =  local.resource_groupname[count.index].resourcetype
      location = "North europe"
    } 
     resource "azurerm_resource_group" "name" {
       # (other settings)
       name = local.json_data.name
       location = "North europe"
     }

      output "local_json_data" {
        value = local.json_data
      }
```

when I run the terraform code I have the output as below:

```
  # azurerm_resource_group.Main[212] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + location = "northeurope"
      + name     = "Wandisco.Fusion"
    }

  # azurerm_resource_group.name will be created
  + resource "azurerm_resource_group" "name" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + location = "northeurope"
      + name     = "Azure-APIManagement-FailedRequests"
    }

Plan: 214 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + local_json_data = {
      + classification = "anomaly"
      + id             = 16020941
      + message        = <<-EOT
            Azure - API Management - Failed Requests
            {{name.name}} exceeds the previously estimated average.

            Please refer to the following reaction process:
            https://apptemetry/knowledgebase/Article.aspx?id=54321

            Alerts generate an AIM ticket, viewable here (search via CI or Alert Name):
            https://apptemetry/AIM/alertsearch.aspx
        EOT
      + name           = "Azure-APIManagement-FailedRequests"
      + options        = {
          + escalation_message  = ""
          + include_tags        = true
          + locked              = false
          + new_host_delay      = 300
          + no_data_timeframe   = null
          + notify_audit        = false
          + notify_no_data      = false
          + renotify_interval   = 0
          + require_full_window = true
          + silenced            = {}
          + threshold_windows   = {
              + recovery_window = "last_15m"
              + trigger_window  = "last_15m"
            }
          + thresholds          = {
              + critical          = 1
              + critical_recovery = 0
            }
          + timeout_h           = 1
        }
      + priority       = null
      + query          = "avg(last_4h):anomalies(avg:azure.apimanagement_service.failed_requests{*} by {name}, 'agile', 2, direction='above', alert_window='last_15m', interval=60, count_default_zero='true', seasonality='hourly') >= 1"
      + tags           = [
          + "Sev:54",
        ]
      + type           = "query alert"
    }
```

Is there a way I can hold the attributes from the JSON and CSV file, and save it to a variable as a string in terraform? and then make a new terraform script from the variables?

My end goal is to try and create a terraform script from a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong. You want to quote the variables that load the values from the JSON file in another Terraform script. So you can use the Terraform module to achieve it. Here is the example:

**./modules/monitor.json**

```
{
  "resource_group_name": "testGroup"
}
```

**./modules/main.tf**

```
locals {
  json_data = jsondecode(file("./Monitor.json"))
}

output "group_name" {
  value = local.json_data.resource_group_name
}
```

**main.tf**

```
modules "groups" {
  source = "./modules/"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "group" {
  name = module.groups.group_name
  ...
}
```

But why don't you use the `locals` block to quote the data in the JSON file directly? It's easier and matches the logic. Of course, it's a suggestion and you can use the method as you want.